# Django: Caching aggregate query?

Tags: django, caching, relational-database

I've got an `Invoice` model, and I want to keep the `total` up to date. So I've added a property like this

```
@property
def item_total(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'item_total_cache'):
        self.item_total_cache = self.items.aggregate(t=Sum('amount'))['t']
    return self.item_total_cache
```

Because `item_total` might get called a few times during one page request and I don't want to hit the DB every time. Is this a good way to do it? Will my `Invoice` object exist beyond one page request and thus the `item_total` might actually get stale?

Ideally, I'd like to compute the `item_total` at the same time the invoices are requested... I know I can do this manually, but the Django admin site, for instance, doesn't know it's going to need the sum. Is there someway I can "inject" this extra tidbit of information so that all `Invoice.objects.all/filter/get()` requests run the aggregate at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good solution, one I've used and recommended before. Your Invoice object won't persist beyond a single page request as long as you don't keep any references to it in a global scope - if it's just created in a view and passed to a template, it will be fine.

There are a couple of ways to get the admin site to generate the aggregate automatically. One is to define a custom Manager and override `get_query_set` to return `self.annotate(Sum('amount'))` - this will ensure that the aggregate is always created for every single query on the Invoice model, which may not be what you want.

An alternative is to define a separate method on the manager - `with_aggregate`, for example - which returns that, but then override the `ModelAdmin`'s `get_queryset` method to return the result of that method. This gives you more control to decide whether or not to use the aggregate in your own views.

Comment: Forgot I could override the manager... never needed to do that before. That ought to work well! Glad my current solution isn't so awful too; might put this off until the more pressing features are complete then :)

Answer (score 4):

Can I suggest another solution?
Why not store the count and make it auto increment/decrement by using signals?

It depends on the amount of reads/writes you have ofcourse, but caching something like this is probably the more efficient solution. And possible quite a bit easyer too.

Either way, you are caching the count properly. The `Invoice` object shouldn't become stale unless you cache it some other way. This cache is bound to the instance and with a new request you can assume that you get a new instance aswell. Unless you're getting your items from memcached that is.

As for injecting the cache when needed. How would that work if you use `get()` or `filter()`? In that case your count would be lower and your cache incorrect. It should be fairly doable for `all()` though. You can simply overwrite the default manager to add this data automatically while fetching. But that would mean that for every `Item` you request, your `Invoice` will be fetched aswell.

Comment: I'm untrusting of signals... if the signal isn't received, the whole app falls apart. A minor syntax error could throw everything out of sync, and it's hard to debug. It's a possible sol'n though.

Comment: @Mark: If you don't trust the signals you can put it in the `save()` method of the model. I agree that it's a little harder to debug but it doesn't have to be that hard. And if you think it's out of sync, simply rebuilding the cache is done in a few lines.